# Projectile not remembering remote projects

Tags: spacemacs, tramp, projectile, helm-projectile

I'm using spacemacs and regularly use Tramp (via `/sshx:`) to open files, once I've opened a file in Tramp I can use projectile without any problems.

However, projectile doesn't remember these projects so I can't quickly reopen them with helm-projectile (e.g. using `helm-persp-switch-project` or `helm-projectile-switch-project`). local projects I've used are listed but not any remote ones.

I suspect this is an environment/configuration issue but can't seem to pin it down. Any suggestions on how to change this behaviour so remote projects are remembered?

Comment: I've been able to save a remote project manually with `projectile-add-known-project` but remote projects don't seem to get added to `projectile-known-projects` automatically